# Are there insects who can or try to avoid colliding with raindrops?

Tags: zoology, entomology

Some insects are very fast. Does this mean that they are capable of finding a way through falling raindrops without getting wet?

Probably they don't do that at all, because riding on a bike or in a car they don't avoid colliding eather?!

Comment: In the case of mosquitoes, raindrop collisions aren't that serious, apparently: http://www.pnas.org/content/109/25/9822 (and related commentary at http://www.nature.com/news/mosquitoes-don-t-let-the-rain-get-them-down-1.10775)
It's out of my field somewhat but I'd suggest looking at dragonflies as they're big enough to be affected by a 'hit' and they're very agile.

Comment: @arboviral almost all dragonflies seek shelter when it rains. I think i read about one exception in the neotropics once.